# Exporting with custom data label image in highcharts gantt

Tags: highcharts

In the below examples, I've tried to put the image of each point (img tags in custom data labels) in the exported file but, they would be disappeared after exporting.
Link of examples: https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/eohdp897/3/

or: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y02sjkvg/

I've also used some related options, but they didn't help me.

```
exporting: {
            allowHTML: true,
             width: 5200,
            sourceWidth: 3200,
            chartOptions: {
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dataLabels` are rendered as an outstanding HTML element, because of the `useHTML` feature. To render them also in the exported charts you need to set the `exporting.allowHTML` option to true.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1zp7het/

```
    exporting: {
        allowHTML: true
    }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work in my real example

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your broken case?

Comment: I think when I use the online URLs for img tags it works, but for my local URL it doesn't work even though I'm using the offline-exporting module.

Comment: Ah, are you trying to export the img from your desktop memory not from the server?

Comment: Of course no, I'm implementing it base-on laravel on my localhost, and images are located there. If it's possible, let me try to separate my chart to independent code and put it on the JsFiddle to solve this together.

Comment: It seems offline exporting ignores the allowHTML option

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your case on some online editor?

Comment: In this example, I've added offline exporting module and it doesn't work correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/meysamm22/m1hbdv73/3/

Comment: @MeysamZarei, as you can see in the console offline exporting, doesn't support the allowHTML option: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/28/

Comment: I see, because of this I've asked another question to figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923019/render-svg-images-on-each-point-of-gantt-chart-in-highcharts